# spring boot cloud config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I want to use spring cloud config to externalise application properties. I have configured config-server and client, but i don't want to use git(enterprise) as source, this is due to the fact that git may be down for the maintenance. Therefore, i thought about releasing application properties to nexus as application.properties.tar.gz and do the following:

1.) When config-server starts, download the release version from nexus and then unpack the tar.gz to a file system on the server where config-server is running.

2.) The config server which will pick the unpacked properties files.

Please note that the nexus url, application.properties.tar.gz version and location are all passed as VM options to config server.

Is this a sensible option? if this not best option, please could you suggest any other options?

Thanks
kankalam

Answer (score 0):

Unless the Git server is down for maintenance so frequently, I wouldn't go with that option, it seems to be an overkill. Also the Nexus server might go down, so there's no advantage on doing that.

The config server does not read the configuration from the repo once and again, the repository is cloned when configuration is requested. From the [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html):

> The default strategy for locating property sources is to clone a git
>   repository (at spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri) and use it to
>   initialize a mini SpringApplication. The mini-application’s
>   Environment is used to enumerate property sources and publish them via
>   a JSON endpoint.

With that in mind, you need to check that the git server you use is available before you start the application or before you refresh its context. If you think it might be a problem, you still have two options:

- Set up a dedicated Git server for your application (Check out [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) as a lightweight option).
- Go the "native" way and load the files from the file system. This way you don't have a version control of the configuration files, but you could do it separately into your project.